# Find integral $I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^4+x^2+\frac12}.$

Tags: integration

Find integral $$I=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{dx}{x^4+x^2+\frac12}.$$

Comment: Ahem. What have you attempted towards solving the problem?

Comment: I tried to decompose it into the sum of fractions, but I couldn't

Comment: Hint: $(x^2+1/2)^2+1/4$

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**$$\left(x^2+\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=x^4+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}x^2+\frac 12$$
Then $$x^2+x^2+\frac 12=\left(x^2+\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2-(\sqrt 2-1)x^2$$
You can now use $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed it before..
I think everything will work out further. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start writing
$$x^4+x^2+\frac 12=(x^2+a)(x^2+b)$$

Now partial fractions
$$\frac 1 {x^4+x^2+\frac 12}=\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac 1{x^2+b}-\frac 1{x^2+a}\right)$$ The remaining is simple even if you need to work with complex numbers (as it is the case here)..